# Prove that $\sum _{x=0}^{p-1}e^{\frac {2\pi ix^{2}}{p}}={\sqrt {p}} $ , $ p \equiv 1{\pmod {4}}$

Tags: number-theory, contest-math, roots-of-unity, gauss-sums

> Prove that :
> $$\sum _{x=0}^{p-1}e^{\frac {2\pi ix^{2}}{p}}={\begin{cases}{\sqrt {p}}&{\text{if}}\ p\equiv 1{\pmod {4}}\\i{\sqrt {p}}&{\text{if}}\ p\equiv 3{\pmod {4}}\end{cases}}$$ where $p$ is a prime number

Can someone give me hints for this, I am completely stuck in this problem.
This was given in my roots of unity handout.

I first, took $S=\sum _{x=0}^{p-1}e^{\frac {2\pi ix^{2}}{p}}$.

The handout asked me to prove $|S|=\sqrt p$, but I am not able to proceed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a difficult result. A hint. This is the trace of the $p\times p$ matrix $A=(\zeta^{jk})$ for $\zeta=\exp(2\pi i/p)$, , so if you can find the eigenvalues of $A$.....

Comment: @AnginaSeng  I don't know matrix manipulation :(

Comment: It's much easier to prove $S^2 = (-1)^{(p-1)/2}\cdot p$ than to prove that $S$ is positive or has positive imaginary part respectively. If the first result is sufficient, be content with that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The following proof uses counting techniques, read with care. You won't need any knowledge about matrix eigenvalues.**

> **Claim 1:** We have the following identities for Legendre's symbol
> $$\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}\left(\frac{a+k^2}{p}\right)=
> \begin{cases}
> p-1\quad\text{when $p\mid a$}\\
> -1\quad\text{otherwise}
> \end{cases}$$

**Proof:** The proof will proceed by counting the number of solutions $(x,y)\in(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^2$ of the congruence $$x^2-y^2\equiv a\pmod{p}$$
If $p\mid a$ then we have to count the number of solutions to $x^2-y^2\equiv0\pmod{p}$ which is equivalent to $(x+y)(x-y)\equiv0\pmod{p}$. The solutions are given by $(x,x)$ and $(x,-x)$ where $x$ varies over $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. Since $(0,0)$ is counted twice and for $x\neq0$, $x\not\equiv_p -x$ we have total $2p-1$ solutions. Now if $a\neq0$ then it's equivalent to $(x+y)(x-y)\equiv a\pmod{p}$. Let $u=(x+y)$ and $v=(x-y)$. Then the solutions to the given congruence are in bijective correspondence with $uv\equiv a\pmod{p}$ as $p$ is an odd prime and the correspondence is given by $(u,v)\rightarrow(\frac{u+v}{2},\frac{u-v}{2})$. Since $\gcd(p,a)=1$ therefore for each $u\in(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^*$ $\exists!$ $v\in(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^*$ such that $uv\equiv a\pmod{p}$. Hence there are $p-1$ solutions in this case. Now we count the number of solutions in another way. We know that if $b$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$ then $\exists$ $x\in(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^*$ such that $b\equiv x^2\pmod{p}$. In fact there are two incongruent solutions modulo $p$ and they are $x$ and $p-x$. if $b$ is a quadratic non-residue modulo $p$ then there are no solutions. Hence the number of solutions to the congruence $x^2\equiv b\pmod{p}$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^*$ is exactly $1+\left(\frac{b}{p}\right)$. Hence for fixed $y$ the number of solutions to $x^2\equiv a+y^2\pmod{p}$ is $1+\left(\frac{a+y^2}{p}\right)$. Hence summing over $y$ we get the number of solutions to be $p+\sum_{y=0}^{p-1}\left(\frac{a+y^2}{p}\right)$. Hence comparing two counts we are done!

> **Claim 2:** As $x,y$ varies over $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, the numbers $x^2+y^2$ attains the zero residue modulo $p$ exactly $p+(p-1)(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}$ times and every other non-zero residues modulo $p$ exactly $p-(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}$ times.

**Proof:** For any $a$ in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ we have, as before, the number of solutions to the congruence $$x^2+y^2\equiv a\pmod{p}$$ is given by $$p+\sum_{y=0}^{p-1}\left(\frac{a-y^2}{p}\right)$$ Now by claim 1, $$\sum_{y=0}^{p-1}\left(\frac{a-y^2}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{-1}{p}\right)\sum_{y=0}^{p-1}\left(\frac{y^2-a}{p}\right)=\begin{cases}
\left(\frac{-1}{p}\right)(p-1)\quad\text{when $p\mid a$}\\
\\
\left(\frac{-1}{p}\right)(-1)\quad\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Since $\left(\frac{-1}{p}\right)=(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}$ we are done!

> **Claim 3:** Let $\omega_p=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{p}}$. Define $$\mathcal{G}:=\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}\omega_p^{k^2}$$ We claim that $$\mathcal{G}^2=(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}p$$

**Proof:** By definition of $\mathcal{G}$ we have $$\mathcal{G}^2=\sum_{x=0}^{p-1}\sum_{y=0}^{p-1}\omega_p^{(x^2+y^2)}$$ By claim 2 we get $$\mathcal{G}^2=p+(p-1)(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}+(p-(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}})(\omega_p^{p-1}+\omega_p^{p-2}+\ldots+\omega_p)$$
Since $\omega_p$ is a root of $\Phi_p(X)$ we have $\omega_p^{p-1}+\omega_p^{p-2}+\ldots+\omega_p=-1$. Hence we get
$$\mathcal{G}^2=p+(p-1)(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}-(p-(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}})=(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}p$$

Hence it's clear that $|\mathcal{G}|=\sqrt{p}$.

To prove the following, we need more work.
$$\mathcal{G}=\begin{cases}
\sqrt{p}\quad\;\;\,\text{if $p\equiv1\pmod{4}$}\\
i\sqrt{p}\quad\text{if $p\equiv3\pmod{4}$}
\end{cases}$$ where $i^2=-1$.

**Remark:** The complex number $\mathcal{G}$ is known as *quadratic Gauss sum*.

> **Claim 4:** We have the following identity
> $$\prod_{j=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\left(\omega_p^{2j-1}-\omega_p^{-(2j-1)}\right)=(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}p$$

**Proof:** It is well known that $$(1-\omega_p)(1-\omega_p^2)\cdots(1-\omega_p^{\frac{p-1}{2}})=p$$ The integers $\pm(4k-2)$ represents all non-zero residue classes modulo $p$ for $k\in\{1,2,\ldots,(p-1)/2\}$. Therefore we get,

$$p=\prod_{j=1}^{p-1}(1-\omega_p^j)=\prod_{j=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}(1-\omega_p^{4j-2})\prod_{j=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}(1-\omega_p^{-(4j-2)})\\=\prod_{j=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\left(\omega_p^{-(2j-1)}-\omega_p^{2j-1)}\right)\prod_{j=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\left(\omega_p^{2j-1}-\omega_p^{-(2j-1)}\right)\\=(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\prod_{j=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\left(\omega_p^{2j-1}-\omega_p^{-(2j-1)}\right)$$
Hence the claim follows.

> **Claim 5:** $$\prod_{j=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\left(\omega_p^{2j-1}-\omega_p^{-(2j-1)}\right)=\begin{cases}\sqrt{p}\quad\text{if $p\equiv1\pmod{4}$}\\i\sqrt{p}\quad\text{if $p\equiv3\pmod{4}$}\end{cases}$$

**Proof:** By *claim 4*, it's enough to compute the sign of the following quantity $$i^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\prod_{j=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}2\sin\frac{(4j-2)\pi}{p}$$
Observe that $$\sin\frac{(4j-2)\pi}{p}$$ when $\frac{p+2}{4}<j\leq\frac{p-1}{2}$. This implies that the product has exactly $\frac{p-1}{2}-\left\lfloor\frac{p+2}{4}\right\rfloor$ negative terms and you can easily verify that $$\frac{p-1}{2}-\left\lfloor\frac{p+2}{4}\right\rfloor=\begin{cases}\frac{p-1}{4}\quad\text{if $p\equiv1\pmod{4}$}\\\frac{p-3}{4}\quad\text{if $p\equiv3\pmod{4}$}\end{cases}$$
Hence the claim follows.

Now let $\varepsilon$ be the sign of the *quadratic Gauss sum*. Then from the two claims above we have $$\mathcal{G}=\varepsilon\prod_{j=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\left(\omega_p^{2j-1}-\omega_p^{-(2j-1)}\right)\tag{1}$$

> **Theorem:** $$\Large\boxed{\varepsilon=+1}$$

**Proof:(due to Kronecker)** Consider the polynomial $$\Psi(x)=\prod_{j=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\left(\frac{j}{p}\right)x^j-\varepsilon\prod_{j=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\left(x^{2j-1}-x^{-(2j-1)}\right)\tag{2}$$ Therefore $\Psi(\omega_p)=0$ by $(1)$. Since $\sum_{j=1}^{p-1}\left(\frac{j}{p}\right)=0$, we have $\Psi(1)=0$. Since $x-1$ and $\Phi_p(x)$ are relatively prime polynomials, we have $(x^p-1)\mid\Psi(x)$. Let $\Psi(x)=(x^p-1)f(x)$. Replacing $x$ by $e^t$ we get the following identity
$$\prod_{j=1}^{p-1}\left(\frac{j}{p}\right)e^{jt}-\varepsilon\prod_{j=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\left(e^{t(2j-1)}-e^{-t(2j-1)}\right)=(e^{tp}-1)f(e^t)$$ The coefficient of $t^{\frac{p-1}{2}}$ on the left hand side is $$\frac{\prod_{j=1}^{p-1}\left(\frac{j}{p}\right)j^{\frac{p-1}{2}}}{((p-1)/2)!}-\varepsilon\prod_{j=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}(4j-p-2)$$ and the coefficient of $t^{\frac{p-1}{2}}$ on the right side is $p\frac{m}{n}$ for some integers $m,n$ such that $p\nmid n$. Equating coefficients, multiplying by $n((p-1)/2)!$ and reducing modulo $p$ we get,
$$\prod_{j=1}^{p-1}\left(\frac{j}{p}\right)j^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\equiv_p\varepsilon\left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)!\prod_{j=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}(4j-2)\\\equiv_p\varepsilon(2\cdot4\cdots(p-1))\prod_{j=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}(2j-1)\\\equiv_p\varepsilon(p-1)!\\\equiv_p-\varepsilon$$ The last step follows from *Wilson's theorem*. Now from *Euler's criterion*, we know that $$j^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\equiv_p\left(\frac{j}{p}\right)$$ Hence we get $$\sum_{j=1}^{p-1}\left(\frac{j}{p}\right)^2\equiv_p(p-1)\equiv_p-\varepsilon\\\implies\varepsilon\equiv1\pmod{p}$$ Since $\varepsilon=\pm1$ and $p$ is an odd prime we must have $\varepsilon=1$. This completes the proof.
$$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

Comment: "Now clearly," really? How exactly do you tell which square root to take?

Comment: Assuming that $\sqrt{p}$ denotes the positive square root of $p$, I don't see how the options $\mathcal{G} = -\sqrt{p}$ or $\mathcal{G} = -i\sqrt{p}$ respectively are ruled out.

Comment: sorry, I am adding that part.

Comment: Sorry, I quickly wrote the solution. But determining the sign of the gauss sum is a difficult problem. Despite having knowledge about that, I showed how absent-minded am I. Sorry to everyone. I will write that part.

Comment: It's a big proof! Haven't read it till now , will read it and tell you if I  get any doubts..
Thank you so much , plus writing must have taken a lot of time..sorry for causing trouble :)

Comment: It's not troubling to solve a good problem :). I am still writing the last part determining the sign. Please take your time and read.

Comment: @DanielFischer I have added the crucial part.

Comment: @AnginaSeng I have updated the answer. Sorry for my mistake that I mentioned "Now clearly"...out of my absent-mindedness.

Comment: @ShubhrajitBhattacharya I said it was difficult.

Comment: @AnginaSeng Yes, obviously. Even it took Gauss 4 years to prove it. He conjectured it in 1801 and proved it in 1805. I have learnt it during my basic algebraic number theory course. I was wondering how I missed it. Thank you and Daniel Fischer both for pointing this out.

Comment: Still your sums should start at 1

Comment: @Diger Which one?

Comment: @Diger, if you are talking about $\mathcal{G}$, then no, it starts at $0$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_Gauss_sum#:~:text=In%20number%20theory%2C%20quadratic%20Gauss,a%20more%20general%20Gauss%20sum.

Comment: For example the first one you claim is $p-1$ if $p|a$, but in that case $k^2$ is obviously a quadratic residue mod p, namely of $k^2$ and so the sum should be $p$ if you start at 0.

Comment: @Diger Carefully read the proof. When $p\mid a$, then $\left(\frac{a+0^2}{p}\right)=0$, so it does not matter. The Legendre symbol $\left(\frac{a}{p}\right)$ is defined to be $0$ when $p\mid a$. See the definition here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol

Comment: Seems you are right and I mixed up the zero in a Legendre-Symbol. But now I think you missed a square in claim 4 (also in the proof), while the "well known identity" actually goes till $p-1$ and not only $(p-1)/2$.

Comment: Also the first product in $\Psi$ in the last theorem should actually be a sum till $p-1$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112383/discussion-between-shubhrajit-bhattacharya-and-diger).

Answer (score 1):

Oh boy! This made me struggle a bit XD. All I could do, was to prove $|S|=\sqrt{p}$ as the handout suggests you to!

First of all, lets re-write the sum $S$. We will denote $\zeta := e^{2\pi i/p}$ and $(a|p)$ denotes the Legendre symbol which is defined as
$$(a|p):=\begin{cases}1 & \text{if $a$ is a quadratic residue $\pmod{p}$}\\-1 & \text{if $a$ is a quadratic non residue $\pmod{p}$}\\0 &\text{if $p|a$}\end{cases}$$

> We claim that
> $$S:=\sum_{x=0}^{p-1}\zeta^{x^2}=\sum_{x=0}^{p-1}(x|p)\zeta^{x}$$

The above claim is obviously gonna help us to deal with the $x^2$ in the exponent. For the proof of the claim, we note that we have
$$\sum_{x=0}^{p-1}\zeta^x=0\tag*{(sum of all $p^{th}$ roots of unity is $0$)}$$
\begin{align}\implies &1+\sum_{\substack{x=1\\(x|p)=1}}^{p-1}\zeta^x +\sum_{\substack{x=1\\(x|p)=-1}}^{p-1}\zeta^x=0\\\implies & 1+\sum_{\substack{x=1\\(x|p)=1}}^{p-1}\zeta^x=\sum_{\substack{x=1\\(x|p)=-1}}^{p-1}-\zeta^x\\ \implies & 1 +2\sum_{\substack{x=1\\(x|p)=1}}^{p-1}\zeta^x = \sum_{\substack{x=1\\(x|p)=1}}^{p-1}\zeta^x+\sum_{\substack{x=1\\(x|p)=-1}}^{p-1}-\zeta^x = \sum_{x=0}^{p-1}(x|p)\zeta^x\tag*{(1)}\\\end{align}and as number of quadratic residues is $(p-1)/2$, we get,
$$1+2\sum_{\substack{x=1\\(x|p)=1}}^{p-1}\zeta^x = 1+ \sum_{x=1}^{p-1}\zeta^{x^2}=\sum_{x=0}^{p-1}\zeta^{x^2}$$and thus, from $(1)$, we complete the proof of our claim.

Now, to show $|S|=\sqrt{p}$, we first investigate $S^2$. For that, note that,
$$(-1|p)\sum_{x=0}^{p-1}(x|p)\zeta^{x}=\sum_{x=0}^{p-1}(x|p)\zeta^{-x}$$and so,$$\begin{align} (-1|p)S^2&= \left(\sum_{n=0}^{p-1}(n|p)\zeta^{n}\right)\left(\sum_{m=0}^{p-1}(m|p)\zeta^{-m}\right)\\ &=\sum_{n=0}^{p-1}\sum_{m=0}^{p-1} (n|p)(m|p)\zeta^{n-m}\\ &=\sum_{n=0}^{p-1}\sum_{m=0}^{p-1} (mn|p)\zeta^{n-m}\\ & =\sum_{d=0}^{p-1}\zeta^d \sum_{n=0}^{p-1}(n(n+d)|p)
\end{align}$$and clearly, if $d\neq 0$, then the inner sum is just $-1$ and when $d=0$, the inner sum is $p-1$. Thus,
$$(-1|p)S^2=(p-1)-\sum_{l=1}^{p-1}\zeta^l=p\implies S^2=(-1|p)p=(-1)^{(p-1)/2}p$$and thus, $$\boxed{\left(\sum_{x=0}^{p-1}e^{\frac{2\pi i x^2}{p}}\right)^2=\begin{cases}p &\text{if $p\equiv_4 1$}\\ -p &\text{if $p\equiv_4 3$}\end{cases}}\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

Comment: may I ask you something? In last part, why "if $d \neq 0 $ then the inner sum is just $-1$"?

Comment: @hew Its because if $d\neq 0$, then the inner sum can be written as 
$$\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z\backslash\{-d,0\}}(dn^{-1}+1|p)=\sum_{i=2}^{p-1}(i|p)=-1$$
where second last equality follows by the fact that, $dn^{-1}+1$ will take each value once except $\{0,1\}$.